# Cuando le doy a la equis de cerrar ventana me la vuelve a abir

Tags: python, cv2

tengo este codigo que me abre la cam:

```
import cv2

def camara():
    nombreVentana = "camara"
    cv2.namedWindow(nombreVentana)
    vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
        rval, frame = vc.read()
    else:
        rval = False

    while rval:
        cv2.imshow(nombreVentana, frame)
        rval, frame = vc.read()
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 27: # exit on ESC
            break
    cv2.destroyWindow(nombreVentana)

camara()
```

La camara se ve bien y tal, pero cuando le doy a cerrar la ventana se cierra pero la vuelve abrir, y asi en bucle siempre que intento cerrarla.
Solo se cierra el programa si tecleo 'escape'

¿Que tendria que hacer para que me detectara el click en la equis roja de la venta como salir del programa?

Answer (score 0):

`cv.imshow` generará de nuevo la ventana en la siguiente iteración si no existe, por lo que vuelve a aparecer.

Puedes hacer uso de la propiedad [`cv.WND_PROP_VISIBLE`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gaeedf4023e777f896ba6b9ffb156f57b8), que para comprobar si la ventana existe y está visible, si no lo está rompes el ciclo.

```
import cv2


def camara():
    nombreVentana = "camara"
    cv2.namedWindow(nombreVentana)
    vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
        rval, frame = vc.read()
    else:
        rval = False

    while rval:
        cv2.imshow(nombreVentana, frame)
        rval, frame = vc.read()
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 27 or not cv2.getWindowProperty(nombreVentana, cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE):     
            break
    cv2.destroyWindow(nombreVentana)

camara()
```